# Is there any better way to handle JSON in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there any better way to do things like this in Swift?

```
var jsonError: NSError?
        let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary
        if jsonError != nil {
            return
        }

if let threadsArray = jsonDict["threads"] as? NSArray {
    if let threadInfo = threadsArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
        if let postsArray = threadInfo["posts"] as? NSArray {
            if let opPostInfo = postsArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
                if let filesArray = opPostInfo["files"] as? NSArray {
                    if let firstFileInfo = filesArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
                        if let thumbnail = firstFileInfo["thumbnail"] as? NSString {
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to give us some more input here. A better way of doing what?

Comment: I suppose the question is: "how do I handle optionals ina more leegant manner, without doing all those pesky `if`s"?

Comment: You could use a library. https://github.com/owensd/json-swift looks good.

Comment: @cncool no, that's not what the question is about. OP already uses `NSJSONSerialization` for parsing the textual data.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant Yes, you're right

Comment: There is swifty json library. https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant  Got the libraries mixed up. SwiftyJSON is what I meant to post.

Comment: You could try ObjectMapper which is a library that automatically maps JSON to model objects. Check it out https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

Answer (score 2):

A little Maybe-monad-esque refactoring may help:

```
import Foundation

let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: "foo.json")
let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

func getArray(a: NSArray?, i: Int) -> AnyObject? {
    return a != nil && i < a!.count ? a![i] : nil;
}

func getDict(d: NSDictionary?, i: String) -> AnyObject? {
    return d != nil ? d![i] : nil;
}

func getPath(root: AnyObject?, indices: Array<AnyObject>) -> AnyObject? {
    var node = root;
    for (var i = 0; i < indices.count; i++) {
        if let index = indices[i] as? String {
            node = getDict(node as NSDictionary?, index);
        } else if let index = indices[i] as? Int {
            node = getArray(node as NSArray?, index);
        }
    }

    return node;
}

let result = getPath(jsonDict, ["threads", 0, "posts", 0, "files", 0, "thumbnail"]);
println(result);
```

Comment: I really like this answer.  You could lose the semicolons though.

Comment: @vacawama :) I'm just learning Swift. I still need to make that a habit after years of Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

A good option just for the JSON side of things is to use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).  That way, you can just write something like:

```
let json = JSON(data: data!)
if let thumb = json["threads"][0]["posts"][0]["files"][0]["thumbnail"].string{
    // The ".string" property still produces the correct Optional String type with safety
}
```